# Persist array data in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have an array structure like thus:

[image]

The data is generated like thus:-

```
$allBreeds = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());

    $i = 0;
    foreach($allBreeds->message as $breed => $types){

        $this->breeds[$i]['name'] = $breed;

        if(!empty($types)){
            $this->breeds[$i]['types'] = json_encode($types);
        } else {
            $this->breeds[$i]['types'] = [];
        }
        $i++;
    }
```

My database schema is like thus:-

```
Schema::create('breeds', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name', 255);
    $table->json('types')->default(null);
    $table->timestamps();
});

create table `breeds` (
 `id` bigint (20),
 `name` varchar (765),
 `types` varchar (-1),
 `created_at` timestamp ,
 `updated_at` timestamp 
);
```

A successful insert using eloquent looks similar to:-

```
$testBreeds = [
    ['name' => 'hound', 'types' => json_encode([0 => 'afgan', 1 => 'basset', 2 => 'blood'])],
    ['name' => 'chihuahua', 'types' => json_encode([])],
];

Breed::insert($testBreeds);
```

How do I normalize my data in order to persist/insert it into the `breeds` db table - i.e. how do I remove the indexes? If I attempt to insert it *as is* - I receive an **Array to String Conversion** error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is a result of this code block:

```php
if(!empty($types)){
    $this->breeds[$i]['types'] = json_encode($types);
} else {
    $this->breeds[$i]['types'] = [];
}
```

You're `json_encode`-ing the value of `$types` if it is not empty, otherwise setting it to be an empty array and not `json_encode`-ing it and you can't insert an array into a `json` column.

Do one of the following:

Update your migration to accept a `null` value for `$types`;

```php
$table->json('types')->nullable()->default(null);


$this->breeds[$i]['types'] = null;
if(!empty($types)){
    $this->breeds[$i]['types'] = json_encode($types);
}
```

Alternatively always `json_encode` the `$types` value even if it is empty.

```
$this->breeds[$i]['types'] = json_encode($types);
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought maybe it was related to the way I structured my data.